# Why is my true false statement before my equation in php

Tags: php

Im currently trying to learn php and started off by trying to do simple math to start understanding the language better. In my code everything I have the bool(true) come before the equation so the output looks like bool(true) 5 and 0 is. How do I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        // // Uncomment the following part of the code 
        // // when your code is ready to use input values submitted by form1.html
        // $a = intval($_REQUEST["n1"]);
        // $b = intval($_REQUEST["n2"]);

        // and comment these two lines of code when using the above code
        $a = 5; 
        $b = 0;

        // Add your code below
        echo "<h2>Arithemtic operations</h2>";
        echo "$a + $b = " . ($a+$b) . "<br>";
        echo "$a - $b = " . ($a-$b) . "<br>"; 
        echo "$a * $b = " . ($a*$b) . "<br>"; 
        if($a || $b == "0"){
            echo "$a / $b = undifined " . "<br>"; 
        }
        else
        echo "$a / $b = " . ($a/$b) . "<br>";
        if($a || $b == 0 ){
            echo "$a / $b (integer quotient) =  undefined" . "<br>";
        }
        else
        echo "$a / $b (integer quotient) = " . intdiv($a,$b) . "<br>"; 
        if($a || $b == 0 ){
            echo "$a % $b =  undefined" . "<br>";
        }
        else
        echo "$a % $b = " . ($a%$b) . "<br>"; 
        echo "$a ** $b = " . ($a**$b) . "<br>"; 
        "<br>";
        echo "<h2>Comparison</h2>";
        echo "$a == $b is " . var_dump($a==$b) . "<br>";
        echo "$a != $b is " . var_dump($a!=$b) . "<br>";
        echo "$a < $b is " . var_dump($a<$b) . "<br>";
        echo "$a <= $b is " . var_dump($a<=$b) . "<br>";
        "<br>";
        echo "'$a' === $b is " . var_dump($a===$b) . "<br>";
        echo "'$a' !== $b is " . var_dump($a!==$b) . "<br>";
        "<br>";
        echo "<h2>Logical Operations</h2>";
        echo "$a and $b is " . var_dump(true and true) . "<br>";
        echo "$a && $b is " . var_dump(true && true) . "<br>";
        echo "$a or $b is " . var_dump(true or true) . "<br>";
        echo "$a || $b is " . var_dump(true || true) . "<br>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would say first to see the indentation of your code, it seems to me that there are missing brackets. Also could you please post your current output?

Comment: learn about [strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) first, `echo "$a + $b = "` is evaluated, you need to instead use single quotes `echo '$a + $b = '`